# How to extract only specific numeric values from a range of data in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a range of data say a1:a100 in which there exist mixed up numeric and alphabetic values.

I want that only the numeric values which are greater than 1 and lesser then 10000000 (i.e. falling between 1 to 10000000) from the range a1:a100 should be extracted and should be inserted into column b.

I am attaching the snapshot of excel sheet.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5qvEdi1.png]

I tried to use this array formula in b1 but this is not working as i want-

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(A5:A100, SMALL( IF(A1:A100>0, ROW()-0, ""), ROW()-0) ), "")
```

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If it is ok for you to use VBA:

Press `Alt` + `F11`, double click `ThisWorkbook` and paste the following code:

```
Sub values()

Dim c As Range
i = 1

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100")
    If IsNumeric(c) And c >= 1 And c <= 10000000 Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = c
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Go back to the sheet with your numbers, press `Alt` + `F8` and run the macro.

I did not test this so create a backup first.

Comment: THANKS dear Divin3..the codes suggested by you are working fine. But i want to use some formula in stead of vba codes. so i request you to suggest me some formula for this purpose. i tried to use this formula but this is not working as i want.

Comment: the formula is this- =IFERROR(INDEX(A5:A100, SMALL( IF(A1:A100>0, ROW()-0, ""), ROW()-0) ), "")

Comment: @user588128 - sorry, but I'm not good with formulas. I suggest you to edit your question, include the formula you tried and specify that you want to solve it with a formula. That will make your question on topic and people will help you fix it.

Comment: @user588128 - the rules here are pretty strict. You can't ask "I want to do this" and expect others to do it for you. **But**, you can ask, "I tried this and can't make it work", than you will be treated nicely and people will help.